# Deletion of the node which has two child in BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to delete a node that has two child nodes using an inorder successor. My node is deleting but after deletion root data is changed to inorder successor.

```
struct node *inorderSuccessor(struct node *root, int data) {
        struct node *successor = NULL;
        
        while (root != NULL) {
            
            if (data >= root->data) {
                root = root->right;
            } else {
                successor = root;
                root = root->left;
            }
        }
        
        return successor;
    }

struct node *deleteNode(struct node *root,int data){
    //if tree is empty 
    if(root==NULL){
        return root;
    }

    //finding node to be deleted
    if(data<root->data){
        root->left=deleteNode(root->left,data);
    }
    else if(data>root->data){
        root->right=deleteNode(root->right,data);
    }
    else{
        //node with only one child
        if(root->left==NULL){
            struct node *temp=root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if(root->right==NULL){
            struct node *temp=root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
    }

    //--------------not working----
    // If the node has two children
    struct node *temp = inorderSuccessor(root,data);
    // Place the inorder successor in position of the node to be deleted
    root->data = temp->data;

    // Delete the inorder successor
    root->right = deleteNode(root->right, temp->data);
    // root->data=temp2->data;
  return root;
  }
```

INPUT:

```
        8
    3       10
  1   6         14
     4  7
```

want to delete 3.
my output- 1 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7 -> 4 -> 10 -> 14 ->
expected output- 1 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 10 -> 14 ->

Comment: Don't you think that the "inorder successor" logic should only be executed in the case where you actually found the node to delete _and_ determined it has both a left and right subtree? It looks to me like you put this code in the wrong place, or you forgot to return after handling the regular `deleteNode` recursive calls.

Comment: Why did you tag this C++ if you are writing C code?

Comment: The not working part needs to be inside the preceding `else`. You also forgot about the case where root has no children. You should also replace `inorderSuccessor` with a function that removes and returns the inoder successor. The functions should take `struct node **root` so they can modify the tree. This makes the code simpler and reflects that they modify the tree instead of retuning a new tree and are destructive to the old tree.